# ClassNotFoundException: Strange Behavior

Tags: java, reflection, static, classnotfoundexception

I have two classes: A and B in the same project but in different packages.

When A tries to create B dynamically, it fails.

```
Class<?> c = Class.forName("com.mycompany.B"); //fails
```

But when I create the class object statically, it works fine.

```
B b = new B();
```

Any ideas?

Comment: In the example using `new` which works, is the import referring to the correct `B`?  Does `Class<?> c = Class.forName(com.mycompany.B.class.getName());` compile?

Comment: Interesting you mentioned that. You comment prompted me to check the class name I was passing to Class.forName. I noticed that there is a trailing space (i was reading the class name from a file) which seems to trip the loading. I am surprised Class.forName() implementation does not strip out the trailing white space automatically. Once I corrected that part, it all started working fine. Thanks!

Comment: This should not surprise you. No method perform such stripping, unless explicitly specified. If you start with demanding such a processing, what about other characters invalid in Java identifiers. Should every method perform such transformations? Besides that, this method is a bridge to the lower level operations and on the bytecode level, spaces in class names are possible.

Answer (score 3):

You have to use full class name, including the package.

For example if `B` is in package `org.example`, then use:

```
Class.forName("org.example.B")
```

Comment: Yes, I am using the full package name. Modified the original question to reflect that.